# Vim: get autoindent but not smart indent in Python source files

Tags: python, vim

How can I configure `vim` to get `autoindent`, i.e. a new line is automatically indented to the same depth as the preceding one, but not `smartindent` (or `cindent`?) where an extra tab is inserted after lines
ending with a ':'?

I'm used to typing `def f(x):<Ret><Tab>...` when writing Python (and C),
so with `smartindent` the first line inside a method (or loop) 
ends up being "double tabbed" (one from the smart indent, one from me hitting the tab key).

The instructions [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip330) to turn off autoindent for a specific file type turn off `autindent`.  I can get the instructions to modify for the current file (same page) to work; apparently `:setlocal indentexpr=` is the key, but when I tried to do similar commands `set ...` in my `.vimrc` I again broke autoindent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is just adding

```
set autoindent nosmartindent nocindent
```

to the $HOME/.vim/indent/python.vim file you made per the link you included in your post.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside: I've been told to use `'cindent'` rather than `'smartindent'` if you're into that (it doesn't seem like you are).

---

Inside python files, the indentation is configured via `'indentexpr'` which is set to `GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)` inside of `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/python.vim` (if you have `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc). If you remove this with `setlocal indentexpr=`, then you get no indentation for that buffer.

It seems like what you *might* want is to disable extra indentation whenever you press `<cr>` in insert mode. You can do that with `:set indentkeys-=o`.

See **`:help cinkeys-format`** for more options. It's also definitely worth reading `:help 'cinkeys'` to better understand how `'indentexpr'` and `'indentkeys'` as well as `'cindent'` and `'cinkeys'` operate.

---

I'd be happy to revise my answer if you need further help; I am not sure you can just turn off autindent after `:`